# Digit frequency in first digit in csv, No import

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, frequency

I'm really a beginner at Python, and I'm doing course in my Uni. If you have tips and advice for this question please, much appreciated it.
I have trouble with writing the codes for the frequency of the first digit in CSV file. 
No import is allowed.
for example, if I have the following values from CSV,
we have to figure it out how many `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0` appears in the first digit in every number,
etc. from `5.385686, 3665, 6942, 4053, 7726, 4601, 7302` there are one 3 in the first digit,
two 4 in the first digit,one 3 in the first digit etc)

I deleted anything other than the number and . from the file. (using corrector for Ascii table)
I tried to put all the data into the list first and returned '5.385686' but I have no idea what to do next..

expected output:

```
[[26, 22, 28, 22, 16, 20, 31, 22, 13, 0]]
```

I'm showing only some part from CSV.

```
5.385686 3665 6942 4053 7726 4601 7302
11754.41657 7859 7002 1502 8754 449 472
800.1759341 2161 4958 3738 5105 1472 2487
1055.19226 7473 3713 4302 3174 6415 9094
1747.798453 2685 5343 3207 2137 1934 1101
2551.157404 3200 4655 2673 4270 821 330
480.7713868 1172 847 3683 9486 2258 6323
19018.97818 3678 5628 1171 7270 8333 2534
505.5652756 7222 4105 6529 169 307 3142
3759.276869 9649 1445 5944 8892 371 8307
4753 6737 906 5057 4401 8698 533
2790 5239 6392 8637 8785 1331 6848
3328 639 3519 7829 6796 3935 2893
6331 2986 6076 1085 7715 8241 5688
```

```
[[26, 22, 28, 22, 16, 20, 31, 22, 13, 0]]
```

This is what I got so far:

```
def filename():
file = open("sample_accounts.csv", "r")
filecsv = file.read()
filecsv = filecsv.lower()
a = []
b = [ ]

chlist = list(range(128))
del chlist[48:58]
del chlist[46]

for c in chlist:
filecsv = filecsv.replace(chr©," ")
a.append(chlist)

ftlist = filecsv.split()
greet = ftlist
a.append(ftlist)

for i in greet:
return greet[0]
# for i in greet:
# return greet[i]
#
# dic = {}
#
# for word in ftlist:
# dic[word] = dic.get(word,0) + 1
#
# # for item in dic: # **** *
# # print(item, dic[item])
# return greet




d = filename()
```

Answer (score 1):

Based exclusively on the csv snipped in the question, you can do something like this:

```
csv_dat = """[your csv snippet]"""
csv_lst = csv_dat.split(' ') #need to create a list from your snippet; you may already have it in your code
fd_lst = [] #initialize a list for the first digit in each
for item in csv_lst:
    fd_lst.append((item.strip()[0])) #select the first character in each entry
print('digit  frequency')
for x in set(fd_lst): #count only unique characters

    print(x,'\t',fd_lst.count(x))
```

Output:

```
digit  frequency
8    10
6    10
9    4
7    9
3    14
1    10
5    9
2    9
4    10
```

Comment: Hi Jack, unfortunately, this is what I'm getting.

Comment: >>> filename()
digit  frequency
[   1

Comment: @BryanNoh I don't have access to your file so I'm not sure what this means. If you can get each entry into a regular python list, the code in the answer should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by string the count of each digit in a dictionary:

```
count = dict({})
with open('path to your file') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        for number in line.split(' '):
            number=number.strip()
            if len(number)<1:
                continue
            digit = number[0]
            if digit.isdigit():
                digit = int(digit)
                if digit in count:
                    count[digit] = count[digit]+1
                else:
                    count[digit] = 1
print(count.values())
```

Output:

```
[14, 11, 16, 12, 10, 11, 9, 11, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you Hussein, but Im getting IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: hmm.. this is what im getting

Comment: dict_values([])

Comment: I entered my csvfile name in 'path to your file',

Comment: which is saved in the same file with this

Comment: Thank you Hussein, if you are ok to discuss in email, please, bryan.noh.adb@gmail.com

Comment: can you print the digit before `if digit in count:` and verify if the code print something?

Comment: I changed th indentation of if digit in count: and I got dict_values([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]), which is slightly far from the expected output

Comment: can you put here a part of your file without deleting anything from the file?

Comment: count={}
with open('sample_accounts.csv') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        for number in line.split(' '):
            number=number.strip()
            if len(number)<1:
                continue
            digit = number[0]
            if digit.isdigit():
                digit = int(digit)
            if digit in count:
                count[digit] = count[digit]+1
            else:
                count[digit] = 1
print([count.values()])

Comment: my csv file can't put in here, there are characters limit..do you mind sending email?